# what does Biometric residence permit mean?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, uk-visa

I'm applying to work in the UK and the first thing you see in the official website for immegrations and visa is:

https://check-biometric-residence-permit.service.gov.uk/

what does biometric residence permit mean please ?

sorry for my bad knowledge, this is the first time i apply for a visa

Answer (score 3):

A biometric residence permit is an identification card that also shows your status as a resident of the United Kingdom.  It's called *biometric* because it includes some information about your physical characteristics, namely your fingerprints and your digitally encoded photograph, encoded on an RFID chip.

This is similar to a biometric passport, and indeed the card bears the same "e-passport" symbol, as shown in https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/261497/brp-information-leaflet.pdf.

I typed *biometric residence permit* into a search engine, and the first result it returned was https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/need-brp.  There, you can learn that the card includes

> - your name, date and place of birth
> - your fingerprints and a photo of your face (this is your [biometric information](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/personal-data))
> - your immigration status and any conditions of your stay
> - whether you can access public funds, eg benefits and health services